# Add subpanel one2many field in suitecrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm new into suitecrm, I'd like to add a one2many relationship between `Campaigns` and `Products`

In a `subpanel` form, as far as I know, I should modify

```
suitecrm/modules/Campaigns/metadata/subpaneldefs.php
```

File, but I don't understand which of these relations should I take as an example.

Could someone put me in the right direction on this?

Comment: I believe you can do this rather easily in the Studio > Campaigns > Relationships by adding a one to many Products -> Campaings. You'll probably have to edit some screens to define which products belong to the campaings or selecting products while creating/editing campaigns. Still, should be doable. Sounds like you might be looking for a many to many relationship though (many products belong to many campaigns) -- otherwise a campaign would only have one product, but maybe you intend that.

Comment: Hi Jacob, if I try that from Campaigns -> Products, I can only add One to One, I don't know the other way around tho, have to try

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve my problem, I need this from Campaigns to -> Products , and Campaigns -> Events

Comment: Not the other way around :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello  I am answering this question according to sugarcrm you have to do it same in suitcrm.

I checked there is only one to one relationship in Campaign Module.

So , try to create custom sub panel withe one to many relation

**1. Create a new link class**

This should go into custom/modules//YourNewLink.php and this class will act as the custom functionality that will build your link between the two records.

```
<?php

/**
 * Custom filtered link
 */
class YourNewLink extends Link2
{
    /**
     * DB
     *
     * @var DBManager
     */
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($linkName, $bean, $linkDef = false)
    {
        $this->focus = $bean;
        $this->name = $linkName;
        $this->db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();
        if (empty($linkDef)) {
            $this->def = $bean->field_defs[$linkName];
        } else {
            $this->def = $linkDef;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns false if no relationship was found for this link
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function loadedSuccesfully()
    {
        // this link always loads successfully
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @see Link2::getRelatedModuleName()
     */
    public function getRelatedModuleName()
    {
        return '<Your_Module>';
    }

    /**
     *
     * @see Link2::buildJoinSugarQuery()
     */
    public function buildJoinSugarQuery($sugar_query, $options = array())
    {
        $joinParams = array('joinType' => isset($options['joinType']) ? $options['joinType'] : 'INNER');
        $jta = 'active_other_invites';
        if (!empty($options['joinTableAlias'])) {
            $jta = $joinParams['alias'] = $options['joinTableAlias'];
        }

        $sugar_query->joinRaw($this->getCustomJoin($options), $joinParams);
        return $sugar_query->join[$jta];
    }

    /**
     * Builds main join subpanel
     * @param string $params
     * @return string JOIN clause
     */
    protected function getCustomJoin($params = array())
    {
        $bean_id = $this->db->quoted($this->focus->id);
        $sql = " INNER JOIN(";
        $sql .= "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE id={$bean_id}"; // This is essentially a select statement that will return a set of ids that you can match with the existing sugar_query
        $sql .= ") accounts_result ON accounts_result.id = sugar_query_table.id";
        return $sql;
    }
}
```

The argument $sugar_query is a new SugarQuery object, the details of which are documented here. What you essentially need to do is extend this query with whatever join/filters you wish to add. This is done in the inner join I've specified.

Note: The inner join can get really complicated, so if you want a real working example, checkout modules/Emails/ArchivedEmailsLink.php and how the core sugar team use this. I can confirm however that this does work with custom joins.

Here is the getEmailsJoin to help you understand what you can actually produce via this custom join.

```
 /**
   * Builds main join for archived emails
   * @param string $params
   * @return string JOIN clause
   */
  protected function getEmailsJoin($params = array())
  {
      $bean_id = $this->db->quoted($this->focus->id);
      if (!empty($params['join_table_alias'])) {
          $table_name = $params['join_table_alias'];
      } else {
          $table_name = 'emails';
      }

      return "INNER JOIN (\n".
              // directly assigned emails
          "select eb.email_id, 'direct' source FROM emails_beans eb where eb.bean_module = '{$this->focus->module_dir}'
              AND eb.bean_id = $bean_id AND eb.deleted=0\n" .
" UNION ".
      // Related by directly by email
          "select DISTINCT eear.email_id, 'relate' source  from emails_email_addr_rel eear INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel eabr
          ON eabr.bean_id = $bean_id AND eabr.bean_module = '{$this->focus->module_dir}' AND
          eabr.email_address_id = eear.email_address_id and eabr.deleted=0 where eear.deleted=0\n" .
           ") email_ids ON $table_name.id=email_ids.email_id ";
  }
```

**2. Add a new vardef entry for the link field.**

For this example, I'm going to create the custom link on the contacts module. So this code goes in custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Vardefs/your_field_name.php

```
<?php
$dictionary["Contact"]["fields"]["your_field_name"] = array(
    'name' => 'active_other_invites',
    'type' => 'link',
    'link_file' => 'custom/modules/<YourModule>/YourNewLink.php',
    'link_class' => 'YourNewLink',
    'source' => 'non-db',
    'vname' => 'LBL_NEW_LINK',
    'module' => '<YourModule>',
    'link_type' => 'many',
    'relationship' => '',
);
```

**3. Add the new link as a subpanel**

```
This goes under custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/clients/base/layouts/subpanels/your_subpanel_name.php

<?php
$viewdefs['Contacts']['base']['layout']['subpanels']['components'][] = array (
  'layout' => 'subpanel',
  'label' => 'LBL_NEW_LINK',
  'context' =>
  array (
    'link' => 'your_field_name',
  ),
);
```

**4. Add the label**

```
Under custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Language/en_us.new_link.php

<?php
$mod_strings['LBL_ACTIVE_OTHER_INVITES'] = 'Your New Link';
```

**5. Quick Repair and Rebuild**

That should hopefully get you started. Keep an eye on the sugarlogs while you're debugging your queries. I also found using xdebug and SugarQueries compileSql function invaluable in figuring out what I needed to do to get a working INNER JOIN statement.

[This is the refrence Link](https://shanedowling.com/sugarcrm-7-custom-subpanels)

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, yeah I'll look for the sugarcrm documentation from now on!